# Mask ROM lifetime

Tags: rom

I have a mask ROM in a synthesizer module whose contents no longer match the expected CRCs, with it likely being just a single bit error.  The ROM is circa 20 years old.

Assuming this is not a manufacturing fault, what are the mechanisms by which a mask ROM might degrade, and do mask ROMs have an expected lifetime?

Comment: Which synthesizer and ROM version? Can you compare to a working ROM?

Comment: @Justme this doesn't seem to be a repair question

Comment: I'd speculate thermal/background-radiation-induced atom migration and dissolution.

Comment: @user253751 I understand the question was triggered by an assumption that the ROM actually is faulty, but what if the ROM is not faulty but some data or address bit between the CPU or just power supply is faulty? Knowing if the ROM contents read with a ROM reader matches to some known reference will help to see if the ROM is not the faulty part to begin with, but something else?

Comment: @Justme the ROM is actually a plug-in 72 PIN SIMM format ROM for an E-mu Proteus 2000.   I built a standalone card reader that on other "failed" ROMs has detected single bit errors when compared to other working ROMs.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a mask ROM and not an OTP, flash or similar? 2001 actually seems rather new for a mask ROM. The storage principles are quite different in each type.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany good question!  Each of the four ROMs on each card does have distinct part numbers on the silkscreen, though, including (C) EMU.   Wouldn't OTP units use an off-the-shelf generic ROM?

Answer (score 1):

["Read-only memory" from WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory#Solid-state_ROM):

> Masked ROM and fuse/antifuse PROM do not suffer from this effect (data
> retention related), as their data retention depends on physical rather
> than electrical permanence of the integrated circuit, although fuse
> re-growth was once a problem in some systems

I agree with that. The problem might come from the physical (external) or electrical stress first, but not from the self lifetime of the ROM. Cleaning the board and re-soldering dry joints may help.

Comment: joint issues would cause an entire data line or address line to act weirdly, not single digits of bits.

Comment: @Alnitak, Curios, I was not clear: Does the diagnostics says a single bit failure? About the cleanup and soldering; Bad contacts can cause marginal signal, if not fail at once.

Answer (score 1):

The failure mechanisms for masked ROMs are no different from the failure mechanisms of the the logic circuits that surround them. There is nothing special about the transistors or circuits of a masked ROM. Manufacturing defects can be latent, and not cause a fault for many years after the product is put into service.

Yes, masked ROMs have an expected lifetime. The value is different for every masked ROM that is made and depends very heavily on the quality of the manufacturing process, the design rules used in physical layout, and the expected operating environment.

Comment: IIUC correctly, you're saying that in effect a single failed transistor (which is not at all surprising after 20 years) could cause the bit associated with that transistor to change state?

Comment: Absolutely. Each bit in a mask ROM is represented by a single transistor. Any fault associated with that transistor, or the connections to that transistor, could cause the effective value of the stored data to change.